# getFragments() method only returns fragments of viewpager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have used View pager in my app for my list fragments (A,B,C,D). On clicking on an item in listview (of say Fragment A) , a detailed fragment (E) is shown. Fragment E is not part of view pager for obvious reasons.

At this point, if i use the getFragments() method of fragmentmanager, i only get the view pager fragments (A,B,C,D) and not E. On iterating through view pager fragments,one of the fragment of view pager comes out to be visible,although the fragment E is on top and visible.

What is the correct way of replacing a view pager fragment with a non-view pager fragment? Why is Fragment E, not added to fragment manager stack?

Here is the code segment that i use while replacing Fragment A with Fragment E.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.detach(fragA);
fragmentTransaction.add(viewId, fragE);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Why i am doing this is, because on some async calls completion, i would like to refresh the fragment which is currently visible to user.

Thanks,
Rony

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replace?

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
// Replace the fragment in the container view with the E fragment, 
// and add the transaction to the back stack 
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,FragmentE.newInstance(),MainActivity.FRAGMENT_TAG_E); 
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); // Commit the transaction
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the fragments looks to be an inefficient solution as it recreates the fragment unnecessarily. For now I have solved it by maintaining a list of my own for all the fragments.